# How do i select row json with the id

Tags: python, json

I have this

```
{"id":"141","bid":4.57000002,"ask":4.89999798},{"id":"345","bid":79933.93185001,"ask":92999.99999999}
```

i am using python
how do i get just the bid or ask price with just an id?

Comment: Firs of all why you tagged `Json`? and what you have tried so far?you need to explain more about your code and show an sample input and output!

Comment: it is json data i got it form here https://www.cryptsy.com/api/v2/markets/ticker i have try'd using there single market data but that is slow because i have to make there api call

Comment: [Use the json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: So you need to mentioned this in your question! and show that what you have tried!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the a list of dictionaries in your JSON data:

```
def get_by_id(lst, id):
    for d in lst:
        if d.get('id') == str(id):
            return d
    return None
```

---

```
>>> import json

>>> data = '[{"id": "141", "bid": 4.57000002, "ask": 4.89999798}, {"id": "345", "bid": 79933.93185001, "ask": 92999.99999999}]'
>>> lst = json.loads(data)
>>> d = get_by_id(lst, 345)

>>> d['ask']
92999.99999999

>>> d['bid']
79933.93185001
```